# creating directory using ant

Tags: ant

The following is my code:

```
<mkdir dir="C:\LabTools"/>
<exec dir="C:\LabTools" executable="${TrueCM_App}\wco.exe"   failonerror="true">
<arg line='-R -S"/LabTools/${TrueCM_Tip}/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_${Product_Version}/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_${Product_Version}_-Build" /'/>
```

first of all,

i would like to create a folder called `"LabTools"` in `C:`, then i would like to execute `${TrueCM_App}\wco.exe` with the parameters `-R -S"/LabTools/${TrueCM_Tip}/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_${Product_Version}/ANT_SASE_RELEASE_${Product_Version}_-Build" /`

why is it that `<mkdir dir="C:\LabTools"/>` is not helping me to make a folder?

Comment: Is C:\LabTools not created after you execute the mkdir? Note that Ant will not output a message `[mkdir] Created dir: C:\LabTools` if the dir already exists.

Comment: What happens when you run your ant script? What happens if you add -v to get verbose output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<mkdir dir="C:\LabTools"/>
```

works for me. (are you cleaning it by accident in some other place?)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are deleting somewhere in code or it is alredy exist . 
Try to run the code again by deleting pre created folder and then check.